# Going back up the tree after completing first recursion branch in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have data in a `myObject` object with the following shape. I would like to get information out of the `downloads` array using performMyFunction() at each level:

```
{
 title (string)
 downloads [{}]
 contains [{
   title (string)
   downloads [{}]
   contains [{
     title (string)
     downloads [{}]
     contains [{}]
   }]
 }]
}
```

I have written the following recursion function which works well for going down the tree:

```
const recurseTree = (tree: any[]) => {
  tree.forEach(a => {
    a.downloads.forEach(b => {
      this.performMyFunction(b.type);
    });

    recurseTree(a.contains);
  });
};

recurseTree([myObject]);
```

My question is once I'm at a leaf how do I then check a sibling or parent branch until the whole tree has been parsed?

Comment: Your code and example are missing

Comment: `following shape` ?????

Comment: Well you didn't write anything about your object nor your function, what are we supposed to answer?

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I accidentally submitted question too early by hitting enter. It might be worth SO adding a feature to confirm the question is ready to be submitted as I am sure I am not the first person to make that mistake.

Comment: @GalAbra and Keith and Nirostar I am sorry for submitting the question accidentally before I finished composing it. How would you suggest I return up the tree? (p.s. if you would like to remove any downvotes it would be appreciated).

Comment: I never down-voted, I did flag `needs clarity`, but I've removed that now..

Comment: @Keith many thanks for that. It certainly did need clarity in its accidentally submitted state. Many thanks for your answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you normally do here is pass another parameter to your function, maybe called `parent`.

eg.

```
const recurseTree = (tree: any[], parent) => {

  if (parent) {
    //we have access to parent here..
  }  
  tree.forEach(a => {
    a.downloads.forEach(b => {
      this.performMyFunction(b.type);
    });
    recurseTree(a.contains, tree);  //let pass this tree as the parent
  });
};

recurseTree([myObject], null);  //we are the parent, lets pass null
```

Comment: many thanks for taking the time to write this answer. I had been toying with passing a parent around because I saw a nice example that had this but still need to get my head around how the parent is used when going back up. The question I have about this now is how do you know to go down the sibling branch rather than returning down the branch you were just on?

Comment: @MikePoole  Not really sure what you mean, your currently on the correct sibling branch during iteration,.. eg. in the above where it say `if (parent)`  if you did `if (parent) console.log(parent.title);` it would console log the parent of the current tree node your iterating.   Also if you want to get parent of parent of parent etc, you can also pass an array and this could store the parents.  Another option is if you don't mind mutating the original array you store the parent on each leaf node.

Comment: @MikePoole  Would a working snippet, that console logs the title, and then it's parent links help?

Comment: thanks for that I've got it working now. Many thanks for the assist, I was close and you helped me with the final part. I'd been tempted to mutate the array but prefer to keep it pure.